# Download a web page with auth using linx from cli

Tags: tty

I have an internet site with restricted access, it requires a user and a password. If I use:

```
lynx -source http://reserved.sindata.it/sinerj/servlet/it.sindata.pgsearch.Sqsearch?action=Showtab&name=arcli > filename
```

I download a login page.
I would like to download content providing username and password, can it be done in linx?

Comment: Have you tried `wget`  (which has a `--password` option)

Comment: @Malkavian there are so many different auth ways. Which `URL-I-NEED` do you use?

Comment: @Yasen http://reserved.sindata.it/sinerj/servlet/it.sindata.pgsearch.Sqsearch?action=Showtab&name=arcli is an example.

Comment: @guiverc I tried: 
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
     --keep-session-cookies \
     --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
     --delete-after \
  URL-I-NEED

# and then wget with load cookies
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
     URL-I-NEED
  
But wget is still downloading the login page.